# Correct way of page separation and inclusion in HTML/Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I'm starting to work with HTML/Bootstrap, trying to have a website with several pages. The way I'm doing it is just to code each page separately, but I see that there are some elements in my page that are just the same (the navbar for instance).

I'm thus asking what is the correct way of separating the pages in this kind of scenario. Is it just to put each part in a separated HTML file, and including it?

I'm using Python Django as a framework and saw that there is a tool called Flask that looks to be dividing the page into sections, is it related or is it a complete different thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is a set of CSS (mostly, there are some JS bits too).

How you share code between different pages on your site is entirely independent of Bootstrap.

You would typically solve this problem using a template language. Since you said you are using Django, you can use the [built-in template system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/).

> I'm using Python Django as a framework and saw that there is a tool called Flask

Flask is an *alternative* to Django. It uses [a different template system](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are looking for a template engine in Python and common option is to use Jinja2 and you are looking for template inheritance check this [link](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#template-inheritance), Flask is a micro framework which can be used instead of Django, but you you have to move from Flask to Django you can use Jinja as template engine in both.